# What are possible causes of an H1 error in a Frigidaire refrigerator?

Tags: refrigerator

Side by side Frigidaire fridge has never had problems. Transported to my new house, had to remove doors to fit it through. Now shows an "H1 error code" but only on the fridge side.

All googles tell me this code on fridge side only may be the "damper". Damper looks to be simple to replace, but surprisingly costly part.
Cheaper to file a home warranty claim.

My thought though is if it worked before, then we moved it and now it doesn't, could it be something simple that we could inspect or give a little jostle to in order to reverse whatever we did?

Answer (score 2):

MonkeyZeus says that H1 means the refrigerator and freezer are too warm. You said the doors were removed to fit through.

Maybe the door(s) are now not properly adjusted for a tight seal. Do the classic dollar bill test. Close the door on a dollar bill at numerous places around the perimeter of the door. Pull the bill out and feel the resistance. There should be decent resistance all around. If you find an area with little to no resistance, air is leaking through that spot, raising the temperature. Adjust the hinges to remedy that.